# Call a WCF Data service boolean method

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-data-services, odata

I'm trying to receive an answer from a WCF method from the client. When I try to execute void methods, they are working fine. For example:

```
Uri u = new Uri(string.Format(LogIn.ctx.BaseUri + "/CreateRole?name='{0}'",
TextBox1.Text), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

LogIn.ctx.Execute(u, "GET");
```

Now I want to call a method which returns a boolean, and this value will be used. Here's the method I want to call and receive its returned value:

```
[WebGet]
public bool Controler(string role, string user)
{
    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(user, role))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the second method not working? If not, can you add some explanation to your answer as to what incorrect behaviour is occurring? I'm guessing that the client is not sending the data back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `LogIn.ctx.Execute(u, "GET")`, try this:

```
IEnumerable<bool> result = LogIn.ctx.Execute<bool>(u);
bool answer = result.Single();
```

Comment: I tried it but it throws DataServiceQueryException and when i check details of the exception theres a "null reference object reference not set to an instance of an object" it looks like the call receive no result.. i've changed the method in the service and put a simple test to return false but no way!

Comment: It worked i had to rebuild/update service reference AGAIN. thanks